# Can't start UI Kitten

Tags: react-native-ui-kitten

I am trying to incorporate UI Kitten into an existing app. I am following the instructions outlined https://akveo.github.io/react-native-ui-kitten/docs/guides/getting-started#new-apps, but receive the following errors. Could you please advise?

[image]

I have also tried to run UI Kitten in a brand new app following the instructions in the above hyperlink. I type in npm run android, and receive the following errors. Clearing watchman watches as advised did not solve the problem. Do I need to have yarn installed to use UI Kitten? I prefer using Expo without Yarn as I found Yarn to be quite buggy with an android emulator (doesn't open on emulator properly).
[image]

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

Open your projects' folder in cmd or terminal, and then try running the below commands:

```
cd android && gradlew clean && cd .. npm start --reset-cache
```